# Is there an in depth classification of branch points in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, branch-points

**Disclaimer:** I have posted this question on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408193/are-there-a-in-depth-classification-of-branch-points-in-complex-analysis) following the instructions of [this topic](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/2638#2638).

---

In complex analysis we have well know results about isolated singularities. Poles are characterized by a 'nice' (rational) controlled growth around it and for essential singularities we have the [Great Picard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Are there a similar classification for branch points? I mean: a clear list with all possibilities and results that characterizes each case?

**For example:** if we compare $f(z)=\sqrt z$ and $g(z) = \sin(\ln(z))$, they have very different behavior, one has a well defined limit as we approach $z=0$ in any branch and the other has a accumulation point of zeros. Are there results that characterizes this 'fast oscillations' of $g(z) = \sin(\ln(z))$ and the 'calmly' behavior of $f(z)=\sqrt z$ ? (May be in an appropriate Riemann surface).

Comment: I don't have a MathOverflow account, so I'll just post my comment here: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Transcendental_and_logarithmic_branch_points) says that $\exp \left(z^{-1/k} \right), k >1,$ has a transcendental branch point at the origin.  So apparently that third type of branch point does have a name.